# Problems When Adding languages with Arabic Letters to spaCy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am trying to add Persian language to spaCy. I followed almost everything which was said [here](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/adding-languages). But when I issue the below command
`python -m spacy train  fa fa-model fa-ud-train.json fa-ud-dev.json --n-iter 25  --no-ner`
I get some errors that I don't know how to fix.

```
$ python -m spacy train  fa fa-model fa-ud-train.json fa-ud-dev.json --n-iter 25  --no-ner
Itn.    N weight    N feats UAS NER F.  Tag %   Token %
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/PATH/TO/PROJECT/MY-PY-ENVIRON/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/__main__.py", line 133, in <module>
    plac.Interpreter.call(CLI)
  File "/PATH/TO/PROJECT/MY-PY-ENVIRON/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plac_ext.py", line 1142, in call
    print(out)
  File "/PATH/TO/PROJECT/MY-PY-ENVIRON/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plac_ext.py", line 914, in __exit__
    self.close(exctype, exc, tb)
  File "/PATH/TO/PROJECT/MY-PY-ENVIRON/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plac_ext.py", line 952, in close
    self._interpreter.throw(exctype, exc, tb)
  File "/PATH/TO/PROJECT/MY-PY-ENVIRON/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plac_ext.py", line 964, in _make_interpreter
    arglist = yield task
  File "/PATH/TO/PROJECT/MY-PY-ENVIRON/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plac_ext.py", line 1139, in call
    raise_(task.etype, task.exc, task.tb)
  File "/PATH/TO/PROJECT/MY-PY-ENVIRON/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plac_ext.py", line 53, in raise_
    raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/PATH/TO/PROJECT/MY-PY-ENVIRON/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plac_ext.py", line 380, in _wrap
    for value in genobj:
  File "/PATH/TO/PROJECT/MY-PY-ENVIRON/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plac_ext.py", line 95, in gen_exc
    raise_(etype, exc, tb)
  File "/PATH/TO/PROJECT/MY-PY-ENVIRON/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plac_ext.py", line 53, in raise_
    raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/PATH/TO/PROJECT/MY-PY-ENVIRON/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plac_ext.py", line 966, in _make_interpreter
    cmd, result = self.parser.consume(arglist)
  File "/PATH/TO/PROJECT/MY-PY-ENVIRON/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plac_core.py", line 207, in consume
    return cmd, self.func(*(args + varargs + extraopts), **kwargs)
  File "/PATH/TO/PROJECT/MY-PY-ENVIRON/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/__main__.py", line 95, in train
    not no_parser, not no_ner, parser_L1)
  File "/PATH/TO/PROJECT/MY-PY-ENVIRON/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/cli/train.py", line 40, in train
    entity_cfg, n_iter)
  File "/PATH/TO/PROJECT/MY-PY-ENVIRON/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/cli/train.py", line 62, in train_model
    pos=tagger_cfg, deps=parser_cfg, ner=entity_cfg) as trainer:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/PATH/TO/PROJECT/MY-PY-ENVIRON/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 234, in train
    self.vocab = self.Defaults.create_vocab(self)
  File "/PATH/TO/PROJECT/MY-PY-ENVIRON/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 42, in create_vocab
    tag_map=cls.tag_map, lemmatizer=lemmatizer)
  File "spacy/vocab.pyx", line 89, in spacy.vocab.Vocab.load (spacy/vocab.cpp:4742)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pathlib.py", line 1151, in open
    opener=self._opener)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pathlib.py", line 1005, in _opener
    return self._accessor.open(self, flags, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pathlib.py", line 371, in wrapped
    return strfunc(str(pathobj), *args)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fa-model/vocab/strings.json'
```

I have Persian UniversalDependency treebanks and have converted them to spaCy's expected json format.
I have added fa language to spaCy in MY-PY-ENVIRON virtualenv.

### My Environment

- **installed models:** en, en_default
- **Platform:** Linux-4.11.0-14-generic-x86_64-with-LinuxMint-18.2-sonya
- **Python version:** 3.5.2
- **spaCy version:** 1.9.0